# Post issues with attachment into mantis through RestAPI

Tags: mantis

I am trying to post an issue with attachment through Rest API.
The issue gets created but the file attachments are not posted.

Please let me know how to solve this.

Below is **my request** details:

```
{
"method": "POST",
"transformRequest": [
null
],
"transformResponse": [
null
],
"url": "http://localhost:85/bugtracker/api/rest/issues",
"headers": {
"Authorization": "aWjAGERB07B9kFgkw8mTm-YIMeDdweJ5",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
},
"data": "{\n \"summary\": \"Sample REST issue-test\",\n \"description\": \"Description for sample REST issue.\",\n \"project\": { \"id\": 215 },\n \"category\": {\"id\": 6},\n \"files\":[\n{\n \"name\":\"test.txt\",\n\"content\":\"dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZmlsZQ0KdGhpcyBpcyB0byB0ZXN0IGF0dGFjaG1lbnRzDQohIyQhQCQhQCQhQCMlI0AhJSNAISUhIyUNCkVuZCBvZiBGaWxl\" \n}\n]\n}",
"timeout": {}
}
```

Comment: What is your mantisbt version?

Comment: Am using MantisBT verison 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mantis REST API specification](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/29959/mantis-bug-tracker-rest-api/7Lt6zkP#2d3878c7-4195-42f7-53b7-9cc11f7501f4), adding issues with attachments via REST is available since `version 2.13.0`.

you can see that here https://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/changelog_page.php

Hence, I believe your instance just ignores the request part with files and adds only the issue description. You have to [upgrade your Mantis version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mantisbt/files/mantis-stable/). The latest one is 2.15.0 currently (10-JUL-2018).